# How can I make holes on a wrist strap?

Tags: modeling, edges, geometry

beginner here.

I'm currently modeling my wristwatch and I'm running into some issues making the holes in the strap. I attempted to use the boolean modifier with a cylinder to get the holes out, and while the holes came out great in edit mode, the object itself is looking messed up, probably due to the subsurf:

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

I've tried edge loops, making a crease, hell, even bevels and nothing is fixing it. Does anyone have an idea as to what could be done to get this working?

Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: [Slightly corrected file.](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2875/). Don't create horrible ngons like this.

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: @Leander thanks for the file, I see what I did wrong in my original.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using booleans for holes is an easy temptation, but often brings horrible results, due to horrible topology. I would try something simpler like this:

[image]

and then let subsurf make the rounding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Definitely won't be using the Boolean modifier for holes anymore, such a headache!

Comment: Note: in this case, since it was simple, I suggested to avoid booleans, but there are cases where you can't avoid them, or they can help immensely (see other answers like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71947/artifacts-with-boolean-modifier/72029#72029 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64567/partial-shape-subtracting-only/64696#64696). Booleans can create easily very complex holes shapes, but since good topology is always your friend, if you MUST use boolean holes, take some time to clean topology after (ie: retopology, a task that is also often needed after sculpting).

Answer (score 5):

I guess my solution is the same as m.ardito .....
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]