# Why mesh getting distrub

Tags: modifiers

I have install Booltron addon. After making the difference the mesh is good after apply the modifier the mesh is getting disturb or losing its shape.
[image]

Comment: The problem is similar to this recent question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap. A boolean operation creates ngons and this is often incompatible with other modifiers (subsurf, bevel, ...)

Comment: @lemon before applying the modifier its good hole punch. After applying the modifier why it create ngons. Is there any other way. For the belt given example to reconstruct but here how can i. Any suggestion

Comment: Because the modifier was on top of the stack (the last one), but when you apply it, the result go to the actual geometry... so the other modifiers are now applied after the boolean

Comment: A workaround, apply the other modifiers and add the boolean again... but of course the modifiers stack's flexibility is lot...

Comment: @lemon yeah i tried that i applied all modifier but the flexibility got lost. Is there any addon will work much more powerful without loosing flexibility. Thanks

Comment: @lemon i have seen in the hardops addon the modifier is applied and mesh also not disturb how it works

Comment: I've seen hardops demos, but never tried it. If possible, please do and report your experience here about your situation?