# Boolean leaves a hollow object

Tags: modeling

I'm an experienced modeler (mostly Maya) but new to Blender. And I'm having trouble with Booleans. I created an odd shaped object by starting with a plane and adding edge loops and manipulating the verts to get the final shape. I then added a solidify modifier and then I subdivided the object. I've added resolution and kept the model in flat shaded. I then want to cut a hole in the model with a simple cylinder...everything works fine, except the resulting object is hollow. I've tried any number of different approached but the resulting object is always hollow. Very frustrating!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and/or the Blend file?

Comment: yeah, a screenshot would help a lot, what do you mean by hollow? 3D objects tend to be hollow, since we are working with surfaces and not volumes.

Comment: usually booleans show issues due to doubles, orphan geometry, negative scale, preceding modifiers, ngons. IDK how experienced you are, but in my experience booleans holes are difficult to make behave well on complicated geometries . sometimes is better create simple holes by hand and rely on subdivision for rounding, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap/74926#74926