# Boolean difference not carving correctly

Tags: modifiers

After applying a boolean modifier there is no surface on the area that was carved by the cylinder. It's kind of hard to explain in words. I have a before and after picture. In the after you can see there is no surface on the first part of the hole that was created. Wondering what is causing this...

before
[image: Before]

after
[image: After]

Comment: Possible duplicate?<https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82503/boolean-leaves-a-hollow-object>

Comment: plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for inspection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following:
Go into edit mode, press a to select all, then w and remove doubles
now back into edit mode, press ctrl+a and apply the rotation and scale.
now try the boolean modifier again

are there any other things in your modifier stack ?

Comment: As always with booleans, check doubles, duplicated geometry, negative scale, unapplied transforms, recalculate normals and if possible avoid ngons. Did I mention them all...?