# Boolean Cutouts

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Hey everyone! I've been dabbling with creating shirts / clothing lately. I'm trying to cut out a hole for my string / lacing to go through. I used the Boolean Difference modifier and it cut the circle perfectly, but the topology has changed a bit. Is there a task I should be performing before the modifier to eliminate this? Or am I just going to have to take the time to even it out myself. Thank you ahead of time for any help / information provided! Have a great day!

Comment: You should never have used the Boolean modifier in the first place. Use [proper topolgy](http://topologyguides.com) instead, it will save you time in the long run

Comment: Try to select faces around the whole and press Ctrl+T to triangulate it - it reconnects newly created vertices to create correctly triangulated mesh. Hopefully it wil l help. But your topology isn't good in other areas too... so maybe try to triangulate whole model first.

Comment: Hi, see this (like many others similar) related question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap

Comment: I suggest you watch this video: [8 techniques of cutting holes in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA)