# Issue with subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I made a circle and then made a boolean cut into it with another circle. But when I apply the sub. surface, the outer circle is fine but the inner section changes into a weird quadrilateral. I want the cut to be in a shape of a circle. How do I solve this?

[image: A really weird circle cut]

[image]

Comment: Booleans always produce horrible topology, see this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove the sub surface modifier
2. Delete the center edge on both sides
3. Select the big and small edge and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the edge. With the f2 addon just press <kbd>F</kbd> until it fill all the edge. Repeat on both sides
4. Then add the sub surface modifier
5. If you need smooth inner side add crease.

[image]