# Boolean modifier not applying

Tags: modifiers

So I was having some issues applying a boolean to a cylinder in another project, and after troubleshooting and come to no solution I decided to see if I could get it to work on a blank project with the cube that spawns in when you open a new project. It still wont apply the boolean modifier. I did try removing doubles and recalculating normals.

[image]

EDIT:
This is the project I am having trouble with. I am trying to use a cylinder to cut a headphone jack hole in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: in this file, your cube has a boolean modifier, but no other object is specified as "target"...  (btw the cube is the only object in the scene...) maybe you wished to share another file?

Comment: Oh I had no idea I had to specify a target, boy I feel stupid. I will edit with the project I am having a problem with.

Comment: Good. A boolean modifier allows you to construct geometry from two overlapping object, either by union, difference, intersection... you always need two objects, and they must "overlap" somehow.

Comment: Instead of marking the question as "solved", accept your own answer. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of using the modifier incorrectly and not selecting my target. The object you want to carve a shape out of needs to have the modifier applied, then the dropper will select the carving object to take the shape out of the one with the modifier on it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Good, booleans are easy to use but often give horrible results, though, in particular when you need simple, clean results. Don't rely on booleans too much for modeling. See this as an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap