# how to dig a hole on a object?

Tags: extrude

[image]

I simply want to dig a hole on a cube. I tried to extrude after creating a circle on the surface, which left me a hole with both ends covered by the original surfaces. I tried the Bridge Edge Loops and got the same result. I cannot find a way to get rid of the surface inside the circle(it cannot be seleted and delete).

I am a beginner hopefully anyone can help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: For a really neat way to make a very clean hole in something watch this tutorial from min 25.45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKxxXzSr5vM It also avoids making any 'tris' or more than 4 vertises polys which is the dark side of boolean operations that sometimes take hours to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a Cylinder and put to where you want to have your hole and how deep it shall be.
2. Add a "Boolean" modifier on the cube. In the settings set "Operation:" to Difference and the Cylinder as "object:"
3. Apply the modifier.

Comment: Nice thanks (+1). However I get [two extra edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdCea.png). Is there an automatic way to get git of them (or not to get them to start with)?

Comment: @cjorssen using booleans to cut holes produces ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices), and they behave quite differently than you may expect. Since you're starting, it's common to fall for the easiest path, but you'll thank you later to not use them if possible: see this related post (many ohters similar): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap/

Comment: Really appreciate your help. This is a easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ngons to your advantage if you want, and this is a way that you can make what you are looking for without using booleans.

Enable Looptools addon first in your user preferences under the Addon tab.

Starting with the default cube, I enter edit mode and change the selection to Face. I select the top face, and then shift-S to snap the cursor to selection. I add a mesh circle and change the vert count to 16 in the operator panel at the bottom of the toolbar.

I delete the top face of the cube, and then in Vertex select mode I select the top vertices and extrude and scale them inward. I subdivided them, and this creates an ngon situation. I change round them with the Circle command in the LoopTools menu under the W popup. I then bridge them with the mesh circle, and then extrude them down in Z into the cube.

I also could have skipped the step of adding the circle and just used the one made from LoopTools on the extrusion, but that would have been harder to place possibly.
[image: face select][image: added circle][image: scale and delete face][image: extrude inward][image: looptools circle after subdivide][!bridge edge loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHwmb.png)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHwmb.png)[[image: extrude inward]][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZa3j.png)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

Add a Cube SHIFT + "A" > Cube

TAB into EDIT MODE and Subdivide it by pressing "W" > Subdivide and change the number of subdivisions to three in the tool panel (Toggled on/off by pressing "T")*(You can add more subdivisions if you need finer detail)

[image: Subdivide]

Select the middle eight vertices and press SHIFT + ALT + "S" and drag your mouse. Left Click when satisfied

[image: Create Circle]

Add the middle vertex to the selection

[image: Face]

Extrude down by pressing "E" + the axis you want to extrude on. In my case it's the y axis so "E" +"Y"

[image: Extrude]

[image: Solid view]