# Why is my model showing different shading on a flat area around a hole?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image]

I tried to make a Scythe, and I wanted to cut holes in the shape, but I'm getting these dark areas around the hole. This happens a lot and it forces me to change my design and I don't want to change my design this time.

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange are supposed to be useful for people finding it in the future, not just for the person asking the question. "Why s this happening" isn't a very useful title. I would not search on google for "why is this happening?"

Comment: Please try to describe your issue as part of the title and on the text of the question. Read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: There isn't any reason to change model design in these cases. Just don't use Ngons + Subsurf. And if subsurfing no need to cut so many vertices circle, 8 vertices would be enough.

Comment: Look at this (possible duplicate) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap/74926#74926

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you simply have smooth shading turned on. In edit mode, in the 3d view, the toolbar on the left (in your picture it says "Add Meshes" at the top), go to the transform tab, and in the "Edit" section, look for a label called "Shading:". Under that, there should be two buttons, one says "smooth" and the other says "flat". Click the one that says "flat" and see if those dark patches go away.