# How do I made little extrusions/details without booleans or edge looping off areas that cannot be edge looped?

Tags: modeling

How do I add extrusions without booleans or edge looping, like a circle extrusion,  I have been asking this question for a while.the circles in this picture are in the base shape's circular extrusions which could be hard to make with boolean and impossible to make with edge loops.

[image]

Comment: You just model them using modelling tools. It is hard to give you a more specific answer without knowing what geometry you have.

Comment: see if answers like this help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap/74926?