# how i can get a good shading of this carved object?

Tags: modeling, shaders

so here you can see that i triagulate the mesh but it doesnt change anything at all, and the other pic i keeped the ngons (that i dont wont in my mesh by the way so i need the mesh in those parts triagulated) and neither solves anyting, so how can i get a good shading of the normals, i am using a normal editor called Y.A.V.N.E to make a good shading to my models but sometimes when topology isnt good, or in carved object through booleans this issue happens in most of mesh objects.last pic is a new model that i am developing

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please search before posting, this is a frequently asked question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/how-can-i-make-holes-on-a-wrist-strap

Comment: yeah sort of solution but ii dont want ngons, so best way would be make plane with holes as one those answer shows and bend it...but i want to do this in that mesh that i am using, instead of creating a new and redo it again